# How important is consensus in mathematics, and what is its role?

Tags: soft-question

In fields like physics, consensus seems to, among other things, act as a guide for what to research, for science communication (and for what to include in textbooks), and so on. I imagine much of this holds for maths, but I wonder if any mathematicians have reflected on this or written relevant papers?

Comment: Similar question elsewhere on the network: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/56044/mathematical-consensus

Comment: The question on the philosophy stackexchange seems to focus on the importance of consensus in deciding what's true in math. This question seems to focus on the process of deciding what topics are worthy to be investigated, published, or taught.

Comment: More suited to philosophy.stackexchange.com, e.g. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/56044/mathematical-consensus

Comment: See https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1a56/939ecc5a1e4fe3a2ca20bf593a5a3c60938a.pdf